# grid block in jquery mobile - background color does not fill in right block a white space is left out

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set background color of divs on click event of it. It works perfectly for first 2 
I am not using navbar or control-group, because I need to have different CSS on different platforms.
you can perfectly judge my problem on:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/srshah23/akDRF/

any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a negative margin on the Jquery mobile CSS. Add below CSS to override it.

**[Working Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/akDRF/1/)**

```
.ui-grid-b > :nth-child(n) {
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks surjith, I was currently giving width to the nth child manually as 33.4%
there is one small issue, but ignorable.. you can try resizing the output window on fiddle horizontally.. and you ll find few widths where it recreates the problem. Still I find your ans much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabs .ui-grid-b {
   border:1px solid #0079FF;
   margin: 3%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-right:0px solid #0079FF;
}
```

Comment: This was silly.. you removed the border itself.. not acceptable.